# Add container to custom page layout

Tags: magento-2.1, page-layouts, containers

I'm trying to add containers/blocks to a newly created page layout. However, they do not show up in the DOM at all:

vendor/my/module/view/frontend/layouts.xml:

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="new-layout">
        <label translate="true">New layout</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

I can select this layout. That works.

vendor/my/module/view/frontend/page_layout/new-layout.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="cake" label="CAKE" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cake" before="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

That container doesn't show up. So I try adding a block..

vendor/my/module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="new-layout" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cake">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Nothing of all this shows up in the DOM..

---

Edit:

The problem was that the breadcrumb referenceBlock was set to remove="true" for all CMS pages. However, for this new layout I want to undo this with remove="false". This doesn't seem to work. I also tried re-adding the block:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="test.breadcrumbs"/>
```

But this doesn't work. It loads the template but there are no $crumbs found so they aren't loaded. If I remove the 'remove="true"' the breadcrumbs DO show.. I want it just to show for this layout. Why don't my 2 suggested solutions work?

Answer (score 0):

In Layout file like `default.xml` or any other request handler file. You need to mention Layout Id as well like below:

```
<page layout="new-layout" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my answer. Can you check what the problem could be?

Comment: you can change the name of block like:
 `<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs_other" as="breadcrumbs_other" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml"/>`

Comment: I did that. I called it test.breadcrumbs in my example.

Comment: with complete template path ?

Comment: Yes. If I write some text in the template file, it does display. However, everything in <?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?> doesn't show.

Comment: that means template is rendering correctly. You want to show breadcrumbs on CMS Pages ?

Comment: Yes. But why doesn't it go through the $crumbs? The original crumbs block (which I removed with remove='true') does show the crumbs..

Comment: is this enable from backend like here https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-show-breadcrumbs-to-cms-pages-magento-2.html

Comment: It is enabled. Because if I don't remove='true' the breadcrumbs, they do show.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64875/discussion-between-cake-and-pankaj-pareek).